# How to resolve Promises in recursive JSON

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, promise

I need to **recursively** go through JSON and **in some cases call remote API**. I need to return the whole JSON modified at the end but I cannot figure out how to wait until *all promises are fulfilled*

```
const getObjectsOfRelated = (xmlAsJson, token) => {
  if (testIfIwantCallApi()) {   
    const jsonToReturn = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xmlAsJson))
    jsonToReturn.elements = callApi(xmlAsJson.text).then(result => {
      return result.data
    })
    return jsonToReturn
  }
  if (xmlAsJson.elements) {
    const jsonToReturn = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xmlAsJson))
    jsonToReturn.elements = xmlAsJson.elements.map(res => getObjectsOfRelated(res, token))
    return jsonToReturn
  }
  return xmlAsJson
}
```

Even if I try to hack it using setTimeout the result does not include parts that were created using external API.

This way the code returns correct structure with promises instead of values **I want it either return completed promises or be able to wait until the promises are fulfilled**.

Comment: `jsonToReturn.elements = xmlAsJson.elements.map(res => getObjectsOfRelated(res, token))` ... in this code, `jsonToReturn.elements` will be an Array of promises ... and in either case where you return `jsonToReturn`, you are returning an object with unfullfilled promise(s)

Comment: nevermind the deleted comment if you read it ... was reading your code wrong - turns out `xmlAsJson` is NEVER JSON, it's just an object - and `jsonToReturn` isn't JSON either - I'd recommend using variable names that aren't confusing ...

Comment: can you provide an example of the input `xmlAsJson` and what you would like returned? by the way, even if you did everything correctly, you don't change `xmlAsJson`, ever, therefore that function will return the input `xmlAsJson` unchanged

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xmlAsJson))`. Why stringify and then parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap plain return values in Promise's using `Promise.resolve`:

```
const getObjectsOfRelated = (xmlAsJson, token) => {
  if (testIfIwantCallApi()) {   
    const jsonToReturn = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xmlAsJson))
    return callApi(xmlAsJson.text).then(result => {
      jsonToReturn.elements = result.data;
      return jsonToReturn;
    })
  }
  if (xmlAsJson.elements) {
    const jsonToReturn = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xmlAsJson))
    Promise.all(xmlAsJson.elements.map(res => getObjectsOfRelated(res, 
    token)).then((results) => {
      jsonToReturn.elements = results.map(result => result.data);
      return jsonToReturn;
    });
  }
  return Promise.resolve(xmlAsJson);
}
```

This way you will consistently return promises and you can use your function like this:
`getObjectsOfRelated(xmlAsJson, token).then(result => console.log(result))`

Comment: You'll need a `Promise.all()` around the `xmlAsJson.elements.map(…)` call though, and then use the same pattern for assignment to `elements` as you used in the first conditional branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Promise.all"...

For a simple array, you map a function over the array:
The function returns a promise for the "new value" of each element.
If you use Bluebird promises, you can even return a mixture of Promises and plain values.
( without having to wrap plain values in "Promise.resolve" )
Then you pass the array of promises to "Promise.all()", which waits for all of them to complete.

To transform a tree-shaped data structure (like JSON), you do the same sort of thing, but recursively.  Each node in the tree would use "Promise.all" to wait for all its child-nodes=, and the root node would only "resolve" when every node in the tree has resolved.

Note that "Promise.all" is going to run all of your ASYNC functions at the same time.  If you don't want that, you can instead use "Promise.mapSeries", which does the same thing, but it waits for each async function before starting the next.  This can be better if you have large data and don't want to start too many simultaneous async functions at the same time.

Comment: Thank you this is the answer i was looking for. Clear explaining of what to do, thanks.